# Where is Julia's findlast() function?

Tags: arrays, julia

Using Julia 0.3.8, I try this:

```
julia> t = [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 ]
1x8 Array{Int64,2}:
 0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0

julia> findfirst(t)
4

julia> findlast(t)
ERROR: findlast not defined
```

According to http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/arrays/ `findlast()` exists, with nothing special about it compared to `findfirst()`.

So what's up with `findlast()` being not defined?  What to do instead?

Comment: It's worth emphasizing that the documentation for 0.3 is at http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/; you were referencing the documentation for `latest`, which means the development version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `findlast` function did not exist in Julia 0.3 – it has since been added to 0.4, but our policy for point releases is to only make bug fixes, whereas `findlast` is a new feature. I've added it to the `Compat` package, which lets you use "future" features in older versions of Julia. If you install `Compat` by doing `Pkg.add("Compat")` and then do `using Compat`, you'll be able to use `findlast` (and the related `findprev`).